# Safe to clean iPad screen with alcohol wipe?

Tags: screen, macos

I ordered a glass screen protector for my iPad and have just received it. In instructions, it says I have to clean the screen with the given alcohol wipe. Is it safe to use an alcohol wipe on iPad screen? I read somewhere it damages the screen...

Answer (score 2):

Alcohol can probably damage the coating on the display. I wouldn't use an alcohol-based cleaner.

I accidentally used an alcohol-based liquid to clean my 2011 MBA's screen and the coating is visibly damaged by it.

See this Apple Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204172.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to clean your Apple hardware use a clean dry microfiber cloth.  It's what I see Apple employes using on all the equipment in the Apple stores.  I've been using microfiber for years on all my Apple devices and has worked great without any damage.

Note:  If necessary you can slightly dampen it with distilled water and wring it out well so it is really just ever so slightly dampened and the follow up with a clean dry microfiber cloth.

Answer (score -2):

Use baby wipes. It works cleans off fingerprints

Comment: Same as using alcohol, could damage a screen coating.